# Get specific values from array using mongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mongotemplate

*I'm trying to fetch the specific values from a document in mongo using mongoTemplate in Java, and trying to map it Into a pojo. Doing so i'm getting error which i'm not being able to figure out*

*My Code*

```
MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(new Criteria().andOperator(
                Criteria.where("projectId").is(projectId),
                Criteria.where("photoList.photoId").is(photoId)));
Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, Aggregation.project().and("photoList.origUrl"), Aggregation.project().and("photoList.name"));
AggregationResults<PhotoGallery> aggregateResult = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregate, "spyne_share", PhotoGallery.class);

        if (aggregateResult!=null) {
            //You can find the "count" as an attrribute inside "result" key
           aggregateResult.getRawResults().get("result");
           aggregateResult.getRawResults().toMap();
        }
```

*Document*

```
{"projectId" : "3380",
    "name" : "single download mongo code base change",
    "seoTitle" : "single-download-mongo-code-base-change",
    "photoList" : [
        {
            "photoId" : "l3Po1WQ5k3",
            "origUrl" : "vendors/photographer/1570125519621/projects/3380/photos/l3Po1WQ5k3.jpg",
            "webUrl" : "vendors/photographer/1570125519621/projects/3380/photos/l3Po1WQ5k3.jpg",
            "name" : "1 (7).jpg",
            "category" : "Pics",
        }
    ],
    "webBanner" : "vendors/photographer/1570125519621/projects/3380/photos/l3Po1WQ5k3.jpg",}
```

*Pojo*

````
@TextIndexed private String photoId;
    private String rootFolder;
    @TextIndexed private String origUrl;
    private String webUrl;
    private String mobileUrl;
    private String name;
    ```

*I wanna fetch origUrl and name only. Thanks*
````